# styling actionBar in android studio 1.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-xml, android-styles

so i downloaded a zip file from  http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/    after i had done all my custom styling , and i added the various drawables files in their respective folders. But for some reason ,when i run my app, the styles on the actionBar hasnt changed. Also i did target this custom styling in my androidManifestFile, that is i did android:theme="@style/Theme.Snapshare" . bellow is my styles.xml file in my values folder.

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Snapshare" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_snapshare
        </item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_snapshare
        </item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Snapshare
        </item>
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Snapshare" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Snapshare" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Snapshare" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Snapshare"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Snapshare"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Snapshare" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ProgressBar.Snapshare"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Snapshare"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_snapshare</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Snapshare.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Snapshare</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Snapshare</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AuthBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_fill</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AuthBackgroundImage">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">fitStart</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/content_desc_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AuthTitle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">60sp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">78dp</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/app_name</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AuthSubTitle" parent="AuthTitle">
        <item name="android:layout_below">@+id/title</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
        <item name="android:text">@string/subtitle</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">false</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AuthFieldContainer">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_below">@id/subtitle</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/login_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/login_horizontal_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/login_horizontal_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/login_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/login_vertical_margin</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AuthEditText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/light_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
        <item name="android:ems">10</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AuthButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_custom</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

also my MainActivity is extending ActionBarActivity, that is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

Comment: Have you applied the theme in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: yes i did, android:theme="@style/Theme.Snapshare"

Comment: 1) This will work only on API 14-20. 2) This will only work if you're not using appcompat-v7 library and target at most API 20.